# Is it possible to get email and sound notifications if iMacros task is completed?

Tags: imacros

Is it possible to get email and sound notifications if iMacros task is completed?

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"(\(\+25\.\d\d%\))" EXTRACT=$1
SET butPos EVAL("('{{!EXTRACT}}' == '') ? '' : 1;")
TAG POS={{butPos}} TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:sell_at_market
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
SET E EVAL("('{{butPos}}' == '1') ? MacroError('\\n' + 'THE TRADE IS CLOSED!' + '\\n') : 'REPEATING';")
```

Comment: Try to adjust the code provided [here](http://wiki.imacros.net/FAQ#Q:_How_can_I_make_the_macro_play_a_sound.3F) . For more interesting functionality of the 'iMacros' automation you may also contact me via e-mail (see it on my profile page).

Comment: Tried that code but seems it is taking me to that .wave file via URL.

Comment: It's alright. Does the macro make a sound nevertheless? (BTW, try the way by means of 'Components' in a js-script as well.)

Comment: No the file didn't make sound. I am not familiar with js.

Comment: Take a look at js-scripts in the default 'Demo-Firefox' folder. Create a copy of one of them and delete the content. Afterwards copy & paste the code from the iMacros FAQ (that with 'Components'), save and play.

Comment: @Shugar Okay, I will try. Thanks.

Comment: How do [tag:java] and [tag:c#] have anything to do with this question?

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
URL GOTO=http://gprime.net/flash.php/youareapirate
```

This code will enter a flash meme page that will alert with annoying sound.
For emails you can extend the macro to enter your own website with a form to mail code. you can even have it send a mail only if you reach a certain `!LOOP` value in case you need multiple runs before alerting.